# Dispatch concurrent queues in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I'm bit confused with the order of execution of `dispatch_sync`, `dispatch_async`, `dispatch_barrier_sync` and `dispatch_barrier_async` when they are put together in a concurrent queue (though i understand the concept!).

I have a custom concurrent queue in my iOS framework. So if the blocks are inserted in the following order, like:

> CustomConcurrentQueue ->
>
> 1. dispacth_sync block
> 2. dispatch_barrier_sync block
> 3. dispatch_async block
> 4. dispatch_async_barrier block
> 5. dispatch_sync_barrier block
> 6. dispatch_sync block.

What will be the order of execution. Can anyone explain me clearly? Thanks.

Comment: When you have two blocks that you dispatch asynchronously (w/o barrier) to a concurrent queue, the order in which they complete is not guaranteed (obviously, because they're running concurrently). In all the scenarios you list, though, you're thwarting concurrent execution via one mechanism or another (through use of barriers, synchronous dispatch, or both) and thus these six dispatched tasks will simply run in the order you dispatch them.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon they'll execute (i.e. start then finish) in exactly that order.

Since you know the start order, I'm assuming they're all invoked from the same queue (probably the main queue?).

1. dispatch_sync. Runs. Step 2 won't be started until this returns.
2. dispatch_barrier_sync. Waits for any previous blocks to finish (but there are none). Runs. Step 3 won't be started until this block finishes.
3. dispatch_async. Starts.
4. dispatch_barrier_async. Waits for the block in step 3 to finish, then starts.
5. dispatch_barrier_sync. Waits for the block in step 4 to finish, then runs. Step 6 won't be started until this finishes.
6. dispatch_sync. Runs. Program only continues when this returns.

Comment: Its not the main queue... Its a custom concurrent queue.

Comment: I mean the queue that you're on when you make these calls. I got that each was being dispatched onto your custom concurrent queue.

Comment: Whether the queue you make these calls on is serial or concurrent doesn't matter for the order in which they execute.